# ValueProvider Issue

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-functions, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to get the value of a property that is passed from a cloud function to a dataflow template. I am getting errors because the value being passed is a wrapper, and using the `.get()` method fails during the compile. with this error 
`An exception occurred while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Not called from a runtime context.`

```
public interface MyOptions extends DataflowPipelineOptions {
...
@Description("schema of csv file")
ValueProvider<String> getHeader();
void setHeader(ValueProvider<String> header);
...
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
...
    List<String> sideInputColumns = Arrays.asList(options.getHeader().get().split(","));
...
    //ultimately use the getHeaders as side inputs
    PCollection<String> input = p.apply(Create.of(sideInputColumns));
    final PCollectionView<List<String>> finalColumnView = input.apply(View.asList());
}
```

How do I extract the value from the ValueProvider type?

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of a `ValueProvider` is not available during pipeline construction. As such, you need to organize your pipeline so that it always has the same structure, and serializes the `ValueProvider`. At runtime, the individual transforms within your pipeline can inspect the value to determine how to operate.

Based on your example, you may need to do something like the following. It creates a single element, and then uses a `DoFn` that is evaluated at runtime to expand the headers:

```
public static class HeaderDoFn extends DoFn<String, String> {
  private final ValueProvider<String> header;
  public HeaderDoFn(ValueProvider<String> header) {
    this.header = header;
  }

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    // Ignore input element -- there should be exactly one
    for (String column : this.header().get().split(",")) {
      c.output(column);
    }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  PCollection<String> input = p
    .apply(Create.of("one")) // create a single element
    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      }
    });

  // Note that the order of this list is not guaranteed. 
  final PCollectionView<List<String>> finalColumnView = 
    input.apply(View.asList());        
}
```

Another option would be to use a NestedValueProvider to create a `ValueProvider<List<String>>` from the option, and pass that `ValueProvider<List<String>>` to the necessary `DoFn`s rather than using a side input.

Comment: I went to google's site on creating templates with value provider and I am having trouble trying to implement the structure. passing options to MyFn is giving me an error of  ''package.this' cannot be reference in a static context' [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Updated the answer to provide two possibilities for your use case

Comment: Thanks @Ben! I was able to extract the values, with the help of your code. I just need to use it for what I need lol